# Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.driver' in value "${datasource.driver}"

Tags: java, spring

When the server starts working (Tomcat,spring boot), the log show this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.driver' in value "${datasource.driver}"

But,this placeholder is not in my project code.

Answer (score 0):

Please look on your application.yml or application.properties

If the value is put on it, you can try to add this config on your pom.xml for be sure SpringBoot use your properties

```
<resource>
     <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     <filtering>true</filtering>
     <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.yml</include>
     </includes>
</resource>
```